# Importing the numpy C-extensions fails when importing a package that depends on numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, visual-studio-code

When I import a package I built that depends on numpy (via pandas), the numpy import fails with the message below. VS Code is not in the picture.

- I'm running macOS Monterey (12.3.1) on a MacBook Pro with an M1 chip.
- I installed Python 3.10 from binary.
- I'm using virtualenv and VS Code for development, but the failure also occurs when I run a script from Terminal.
- I built a package (PyTables) that uses pandas and numpy: [PyTables](https://test.pypi.org/project/pytables/). It runs just fine in that project on my machine.
- However, when install that built package in another project -- `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ pytables` -- and then import it -- `import pytables as tp` -- I get the numpy import error below.
- I've isolated the problem to just that import statement.
- I installed pandas 1.4.1 and numpy 1.22.1 in this virtualenv using pip3, just as I did in the env where I built the package.
- I also have Python 3.9.1 on my system. I need 3.10 for PySimpleGUI.
- If I simply comment out the import, the code runs fine.

Import error:

> ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
> many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
> installed.
>
> We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
>
> ```
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
> ```
>
> Please note and check the following:
>
> - The Python version is: Python3.10 from
>   "/Users/alecramsay/.virtualenvs/tstudio/bin/python"   * The NumPy
>   version is: "1.22.1"
>
> and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully
> study the documentation linked above for further help.
>
> Original error was:
> dlopen(/Users/alecramsay/.virtualenvs/tstudio/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried:
> '/Users/alecramsay/.virtualenvs/tstudio/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need
> 'x86_64'))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If I understand the "original error" message correctly, it has the arm64 version (which is what I need for the M1) but it says it needs the x86_64 version, so it seems the import is looking for the wrong version for some reason.

Again, the package works fine in its project. It's only when trying to import the built/distributed version that the numpy import fails.

Comment: This didn't happen when I was using Python 3.9, just now that I've installed 3.10. It also doesn't happen outside VS Code. IOW, I can start Python and import my pytables package just fine *outside* VS Code, but if I'm in VS Code and try the same import, I get this numpy import error. From various bits of info, it sounds like some sort of VS Code environment activation error. numpy is in the virtual environment site packages.

Comment: Anyone else having this VS Code environment activation issue? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19238

Comment: The problem turned out to be that I was running an old non-univeral / non-Apple silicon version of VS Code on my new M1-based Macbook -- I set it up using a Time Machine image. Almost everything worked just fine, except importing pandas inside VS Code croaked because the platform was wrong. User error.